# How to resolve errors resulting from Volley post method that does not complete?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

My mainactivity class is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url="http://onam.leah.in/android_login_api/register_json.php";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    hideDialog();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user","swaroop");

            return params;
        };
    };
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

I tried to send the the details to url:http://onam.leah.in/android_login_api/register_json.php,null

My log cat is below

> Process: harico.jsonexam2, PID: 21185
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.ProgressDialog.isShowing()' on a null object reference
>               at harico.jsonexam2.MainActivity.hideDialog(MainActivity.java:75)
>               at harico.jsonexam2.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:29)
>               at harico.jsonexam2.MainActivity$2.onErrorResponse(MainActivity.java:57)
>               at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:598)
>               at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // create instance in onCreate()
```

...

use it in callback response

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
           void run() {
               hideDialog();
           }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but in my case its not working.can you suggest any other methods to handle this pblm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is correct url?

```
url="http://onam.leah.in/android_login_api/register_json.php,null";
```

the last part looks incorrect

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake the actual url link is url="http://onam.leah.in/android_login_api/register_json.php";

Answer (score 0):

`pDialog` is null. Create the instance for the `ProgressDialog` .

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,i added the i created the insatnce but now  the app crashes and log cat is                                                                      Process: harico.jsonexam2, PID: 22472
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.ProgressDialog.isShowing()' on a null object reference
            at harico.jsonexam2.MainActivity.hideDialog(MainActivity.java:75)
            at harico.jsonexam2.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:29)
            at harico.jsonexam2.MainActivity$2.onErrorResponse(MainActivity.